# Scale Bones Visually 2.92

Tags: mesh, rigging

So I have downloaded a model from 'The Models Resource' and the bones on the model are very small and you have to zoom in a ton to actually see them. Anyway I was just wondering if there is a way to visually scale the bones without deforming the mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You just need to scale them in edit mode, not pose mode. Select all, then set the reference for operations from the default “median point“ to “individual origins,“ and scale.

[image]

Comment: PS: I made a script designed to edit such armatures and make them more standard, with a little post-processing to the taste. Here is a link to it on GitHub (warning: it does not respect original animations orientation). https://github.com/thelabcat/SMD-Model-PostImport